# What's the aircraft painting standard?

Tags: wing

Why are wings always painted grey, regardless of the color of the fuselage? Is there a regulation for that issue?

Comment: Just a suspicion: Painting a plane costs money and the paint adds weight. The wings aren't nearly as visible* to the paying public as the side of the fuselage or the vertical stab, so there's less benefit from spending the cash and adding the weight, therefore it's not done. *About the only time you see them is when you're in the terminal, standing at the windows and looking down at the plane. On my last several trips, the only people doing that were under the age of 10 and they don't have much purchasing power.

Comment: Your assumption isn't correct, grey is a common color but not the only one wings will be painted.

Comment: @FreeMan The wings on planes owned by every airline I just looked at just now were definitely painted and not "bare" aluminium (which would actually be clear-coated but that's still less weight than paint plus clear-coat).

Comment: @DavidRicherby valid point. I was thinking "painted with company logo/advertising" not "painted to be finished" as is indicated in the duplicate (for with I voted).

Comment: Most of the commercial airplanes I see going overhead (I'm about 10 miles from the approach end of the runway) are painted white, not grey, at least on the bottom.  And the top side of the wings is about the only part of the outside of a plane that a passenger can see.